# Undefined variable: UserModel. Trying to display the content from the Authenticatable Model

Tags: mysql, laravel, xampp

I am trying to display the things but resulting into an error where the other things i have displayed but as in model there is Authenticate used i am not getting it how to display. As i don't have much experience with laravel

Route :

```
Route::post('profile', 'RegisterController@show');
```

Controller:

```
public function show()
    {
        $UserModel=UserModel::all();
        return view('profile')->with('UserModel',$UserModel);
    }
```

Model:
namespace App;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Input;
use Hash;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class UserModel extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table = 'doctor_dbs';
    protected $primaryKey = 'doc_id';

    protected $fillable=['doctor_name','contact_no','email'];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password','password_again','remember_token',
    ];


    public static function UserStore($data)
    {
        $doctor_name = Input::get('doctor_name');
        $contact_no = Input::get('contact_no');
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

        $users = new UserModel();

        $users->doctor_name=$doctor_name;
        $users->contact_no=$contact_no;
        $users->email=$email;
        $users->password=$password;

        $users->save();
    }
}
```

view as Profile filename:

```
 @foreach($UserModel as $key=>$row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$row->doctor_name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{$row->contact_no}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{$row->email}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: And in Route its as: Route::post('profile', 'RegisterController@show');

Comment: Can you add your imports in the model ??

Comment: I have added it please check @Maraboc

Comment: All is OK, can you add a dd in the show method like this `$UserModel=UserModel::all(); dd($UserModel);` and tel me what is the output ?

Comment: No i am not getting any output. @Maraboc

Comment: You get the same error ??

Comment: yup i got the same error @Maraboc

Comment: So the show method is not called at all !!

Comment: Is there any other method that return `view('profile')` ??

Comment: nope not called i m getting the same error. @Maraboc

Comment: What is the you current URL in the browser ??

Comment: http://localhost:8000/profile this is the url. @Maraboc

Comment: Ok then change you route from `Route::post('profile', 'RegisterController@show');` to `Route::get('profile', 'RegisterController@show');` !! and i think you have alredy a route like this with other method aren't you ??

Comment: it is displaying but the data is been repeated @Maraboc

Comment: Sorry i am not allowed to chat their as i dont have required reputations. If possible please mail me at amurutapatil23@gmail.com @Maraboc

Comment: Did you find out the problem ??